# Why Clipboard.GetFileDropList() returns an empty collection on Remote Desktop?

Tags: c#, clipboard, remote-desktop

I have a program on which I need to be able to copy and paste from a remote computer, to my local computer.

My problem is, when I use

```
Clipboard.GetDropList();
```

it returns a collection with 0 elements, no matter how many elements I tried to copy.

I tried it with :

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
{
    foreach (string item in Clipboard.GetFileDropList())
    {
        File.Copy(item, path + '\\' + Path.GetFileName(item));
    }
}
```

I also tried ([BoltBait's answer](http://enter%20link%20description%20here)):

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection idat = null;
Exception threadEx = null;
Thread staThread = new Thread(
    delegate ()
    {
        try
        {
            idat = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            threadEx = ex;
        }
    });
staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
staThread.Start();
staThread.Join();
```

Both versions return an empty collection.

Where could the problem come from? Knowing that:

- Copy/Pasting from Remote to local (via windows) works
- Copy/Pasting from Local to Local (via code) works
- Clipboard sharing is activated
- OS (Local) : Windows 10
- OS (Remote) : Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get an empty collection is the fact that the clipboard doesn't contain any data in the [`DataFormats.FileDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.filedrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) format.

Instead, on copying some files on a remote machine via Remote Desktop (while the clipboard sharing is enabled), the file contents will be placed in the clipboard directly. The clipboard will contain the data in following formats:

- [`FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (actually, `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORA` or `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW`, on your system - the second one)
- [`CFSTR_FILECONTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- `CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT`

So theoretically you could try to iterate through the `FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR` objects and store each file reading its `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` from the clipboard.

But I found a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1078948/cannot-get-all-files-from-remote-desktop-clipbaord-with-the-idataobject-getdata-string-format) describing that this only works for the first file in Windows Forms. So you will have to implement it using P/Invoke by calling the native methods.

Comment: When I try to access FileContents I get an exception (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA HRESULT : 0x800401D3) (I'm using GetData("FileContents") ). Is there another method I should use ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not well supported by the `Clipboard` implementation in .NET. You have to switch to unmanaged approach - either via P/Invoke or by creating your own unmanaged module. For details, see [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#filecontents).